# Setting attribute of HTML element only affects node, not actual element

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I am having an infuriating problem which is produced by following code:

```
function setPeriodTimes(day, period, from, to) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("day" + day)[0].children[period - 1].setAttribute("from", from)
    document.getElementsByClassName("day" + day)[0].children[period - 1].setAttribute("to", to)
}
```

it doesn't throw an error, however, when using this function, then looking in the console with

```
document.getElementsByClassName("day" + 1)[0].children[1].getAttribute("to")
```

I get the expected result, however looking at the elements page in the dev toolbox, I don't see the updated attribute values.

It is rather annoying and is preventing me from continuing... any advice would be most appreciated.

Thankyou Jacob.

Comment: check the 'day' 'period' value in your function. Are they the value you expected?

Comment: They are, it is all correct because when I look them up in the JS console, it returns the value that I expect, they just don't show up on the actual HTML elements that I can view in the elements tab in the dev tools.

Comment: Then what will you do with the attributes? Such as some other function read those values? If other functions can read the attributes values, then no problem, right?

Comment: Well, yes, good point, but actually I wanted to read through all the tags with specific attributes, then convert it to JSON to be sent to a server for further processing

Comment: You can start from read through all the tags, and log out the attributes you want to check, if the expected value got logged out, then your following logic can be continued, right?

Comment: That is probably a much smarter approach to the same problem